# How to capture focus for either an input OR a textarea

Tags: jquery

I would like to detect when an input or textarea has recieved focus. For input I have:

```
$('body').on('focus','input', function(){
```

How would I add textarea to this? Tried

```
$('body').on('focus',['input','textarea'], function(){
```

but no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input, textarea', function () { ... });
```

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [Multiple selectors (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)